# Rust: static objects or something like Java Spring Component

Tags: rust, static, mutex

I am building an application using Rust + Iced. I have various services for creating and manipulating my data. As of now I have one struct that contains all of the services and I pass it around as needed. But its growing more and more complicated and therefore, I was wondering if making this object static (or making the services singletons with something called Mutex) is bad design in Rust. What I would like to have is something like Spring Component, resp. ApplicationContext in java. I just "autowire" the service where it is needed, or I just use some global static that contains this services.

Just to give more context: now I have one service, that needs to observe changes in other services in order to recalculate, then for the calculation it actually needs to use 3 different services and it needs to be mutable. When I tried to implement Observer for this, I suddenly had to add a lot more places where I am handing over the Services object and it has to be mutable, because I need the one service mutable.

Here is a simplification of the services structure:

```rust
pub mod foo_service;
pub mod bar_service;
pub mod calculated_service;
pub mod etc_service;
...

// object implementing this trait needs to be available everywhere, passing it around means having this as argument almost everywhere
pub trait LibServices {
    fn get_foo_service(&self) -> &FooService;
    fn get_bar_service(&self) -> &BarService;
    fn get_calculated_service(&self) -> &CalculatedService;
    fn get_etc_service(&self) -> &EtcService;
}
```

Comment: It is generally considered good practice to avoid global values, because they make code harder to test. Now, if you absolutely need to have global values, you can indeed have `static` + `Mutex`, but I'm not sure that it is going to decrease the amount of `mut`-tracking you'll end up doing.

Comment: Thanks. And I assume there is no such thing as dependency injection in Rust, right?

Comment: Not really, but you can use `static` + `OnceLock` to achieve something similar, e.g.
```rust
fn get_my_dependency() -> &'static Foo {
   static ONCE: OnceLock<Foo> = OnceLock::new();
   ONCE.get_or_init(|| Foo::new())
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will read about this a bit. :)

Comment: I think [AOP](https://github.com/trusted-programming/cargo-aspect) also can help in this kind of situations.